# Get variable file name in ansible

Tags: ansible, devops

While running ansible playbook with a command like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory -e @abc.yml -e @xyz.yml
```

How to get the variable file name: xyz.yml. or abc.yml.

The requirement is to create some resources based on the variable file name. This requires passing the variable file name into a variable in the playbook.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) If the answer below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to get ansible command line inside a play.

If you want to change play behavior based on variables filename, I'd advise you to pass filename with variables as an argument and load variables dynamically:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory -e data_source=abc.yml
```

insde your `playbook.yaml`:

```
- name: Load additional variables
  include_vars:
    file: '{{ data_source }}'
  when: data_source is defined

- name: Do something is datasource is abc
  command: echo do something
  when: data_source|default('') == 'abc.yaml'
```

`include_vars` operates on ansible controller host (host where ansible-playbook binary is run), so it's an more or less an equivalent of '@' command line feature.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.